# Is it possible to get Vray like renders using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I deal with architectural visualization. I have used Vray before and I have gotten excellent results. I am struggling to get the same or about the same results with cycles. So my question is...is it possible to get the same or about the same results with cycles as it is with vray?

Thank you

Comment: Largely yes. not *exactly* the same, but when you're skilled enough for it to make a difference, you'll know what render engine you need. For now cycles will do just fine, some truly incredible renders have been made with cycles.

Comment: I've seen some good results such as http://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/07/08/architectural-contest-results/ http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/interior-3d-architectural-visualization/ http://www.thearchitectureacademy.com

Comment: can you share an example?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/how-is-cycles-different-from-v-ray/14270#14270

Comment: This type of result is technically possible, but will depend on your expertise in Cycles. The render engine will not be the limitation (it may be harder, though). I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Comment: The two are based on basically the same principals.  The main difference is the way they define materials.  The cycles nodes system can be harder to learn for most people, but it can be *much* more flexible (and in my mind often simpler) once you get the hang of it.  So, as the others have said, you can get basically the same results, it's just a different way of going about it.

Comment: I have the same situation. In Cycles I'm playing a lot with compositor and post-production (dark-table) which can help, but V-ray still is much better in terms of realism and professional results, even without post production. Have you find a way to improve Cycles?